# Why can't i use a var inside a .get()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use .get() to refresh my page without actually refreshing or reloading. But I can't seem to get it to load the variable I've set up to load its own url. Here is what I have.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    pathName = ".." + loc.substring(50, loc.href.lastIndexOf('.') + 4);
    alert(pathName);

    $.get("pathName", function(data) {
        $('#pagebody').html(data);
    });
}, 2000);
```

The alert gives me what I want which is ../out/G56.HTM, when I type in ../out/G56.HTM it works fine, the problem is there are 56 different pages from G1 to G56.HTM. I've also tried have it load only G56.HTM that doesn't work either. However if it type in $.get('G56.HTM', function...) that works as well, I can't get it to read the variable???

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.


Comment: How was I supposed to know it was a syntax error?

Comment: I'm not blaming you for posting it - don't take offense. The rationale to close this question is that it is highly unlikely to help future users. We're not angry at you these things happen to everyone :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a spelling error. You put `"pathName"` in quotes which means it treats it like a string.

Try

```
$.get(pathName, function(data) {
```

Comment: Thank you, wow I've been beating myself up over that for awhile.

Comment: Is there a reason why two certain symbols don't show up when the .get() takes place?

Comment: @chrisw.iec what do you mean?

Comment: when I reload the data from the page itself it replaces the symbols with square boxes. When the page first loads they are there when the `$.get();` loads they are replaced with boxes.